# Do we accept questions on Sports Officials?

Tags: discussion, area51

There is a proposal for a site called "[Sports Officials](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/56121/sports-officials)", which it has been suggested is merged with this site.

Is there any reason why questions about Sports Officiating (refereeing, umpiring) would not be welcome here?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any reason why questions about Sports Officiating (refereeing, umpiring) would not be welcome here?

None at all. In fact, we have 36 questions on [`officiating`](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/officiating) thus far.